Cannot find autodesk webhook to listen for issues
I am currently working on integrating my company's web service with autodesk, so far everything has gone perfect but a couple of days ago I had the need to retrieve the issues that had been updated, similar to the models using a webhook in the data system, however I could not find a way to do this, I tried adding all the possible webhooks for a folder but I didnt receive any notifications when I created new issues.
curl -v '   https://developer.api.autodesk.com/webhooks/v1/systems/data/hooks' \
  -X 'POST' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'x-ads-region: EMEA' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer [acc_token]' \
  -d '{
    "callbackUrl": "http://myCallbackUrl.com",
    "scope": {
        "folder": "urn:adsk.wipemea:fs.folder:[folder_id]"
    }
}'

That endpoint just saves the whole string in a database so it's not an error blocking the execution of my code when trying to decode the string or anything like that, also the rest of the notifications do work.
I also tried adding the hooks for the model derivative but I didn't have any luck there either, as far as I can see on the documentation I cannot find any hooks specifically for issue creation, editing or removal.
Thank you for your help, I would just like to know if there is a way to create a web hook that detects changes in issues and if so, how do I use it, if there is not I will have to change my approach to this problem.

Authentication API v1 has been deprecated https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/authentication-v2-and-deprecation-v1

APS does not currently provide webhook events for issues. The list of supported events can be found here:

Data Management events
Model Derivative events
Revit Cloud Worksharing events
Fusion Lifecycle events
Cost Management events
BuildingConnected events


Thank you very much, I thought this was the case but I wanted to ask just in case, I will have to change my approach.
